# Mysql with regular expression

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query regarding regular expression.I have design a table which contain three column one column contain member ids which are separated by commas.I am showing you my table structure.Please follow

```
send_id    member_id

1          1211,23,34
2          1,23
```

I want to select only send_id 2 data which contain member_id as 1.

this is the query that i am using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[1]+$';
```

but this query giving me both row.Please help me.

With Regards

Rahul

Comment: You need to normalize your data.

Comment: "one column contain member ids which are seperated by commas" - yeah, that's where you slipped up

Comment: There are 1s in both rows, therefore it'll return both. As mentioned above, you need to normalise your data

Comment: He doesn't necessarily need to normalize the data.  He could be doing a NoSQL using SQL.

Answer (score 5):

**Never store separate values in one column**

Normalize your structure like

```
send_id    member_id

1          1211
1          23
1          34
2          1
2          23
```

If you still want your regex, then it will be

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE column REGEXP '(^|[^0-9])1([^0-9]|$)'
```

Comment: actually i don't want to create large number of rows,thats why i am using this method to store the id,Please suggest me i am going to right path?

Comment: Your reason is totally incorrect. Overhead to deal with delimiter-separated values is much, much, **much** higher than time, which will DB spend on inserting extra-rows. That is about normalization and basic relation-DB principles. You can read about that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Comment: Sure I am going to normalize the tablews

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be normalizing your data so you're not in this horrible mess in the first place. [Here's a good resource explaining normalization.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Second, I believe your problem lies with your regular expression. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[1]$';
```

The regular expression you're using uses the `[1]+` group. The `+` means it has to match `[1]` 1 or more times, hence why you're getting two rows instead of one. Removing the `+` means it will match `[1]` once.

However, that still won't fix your problem, as more than one row contains `1`. This is why normalization is so important.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple values inside a column isn't a good practice for designing a DB.
You should normalize your data, i.e., put just one piece of atomic information inside each element of your table.

You can find more information regarding to this in Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

depending on your requirements, you should either normalize your data i.e. make 3 tables, one with the send ID, one with the member id, and one that combines the two, then you can link them up with INNER JOINS.

However, if you are going to do it that way, you can use a `"WHERE member_id LIKE %1%"` to pull in all the relevant fields.  You'll have to use the application to filter the relevant records.

In any case, if you're not going to normalize the data you will have to use the front end to filter out the results.

An example of the inner join syntax would look like this

```
SELECT * FROM SendTable
     JOIN Send_Member ON SendTable.send_id = Send_Member.send_id
     JOIN Member ON Member.member_id = Send_Member.member_id
     WHERE Member.member_id = 1;
```

where the schema looks like:

```
Sendtable:
send_Id (primary key)
...other fields

Send_Member:
send_id (primary key and foreign key to SendTable)
member_id (primary key and foreign key to member)
...any fields you might want that are relevant to the particular send table and member table link

Member:
member_id (primarykey)
...other fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Like they have told you, perfect solution would be normalize your data, I think [Alma Do Mundo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637490/alma-do-mundo) answer explains it quite well.

If you want to use REGEXP anyway you have to take in account four approaches; *id* is the only one, *id* is the first, *id* is in the middle and *id* is at the end. I have use *id=74* for the example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE member_id REGEXP '(^74$|^74,|,74,|,74$)';
```